# Error 0x800701e3 when trying to install Windows Server 2019

Tags: hard-drive, usb, iso-image, windows-installation, windows-server

I always get the same error code, even when I enter the product key. I downloaded 2 different builds of Windows Server - Build 17046 and Build 17666; both didn't work. I'm assuming that this isn't something wrong with the ISO files I downloaded. I'm burning these ISOs to a 16 GB flash drive (which is USB 3.0). I used Rufus 3.0 to burn it (filesystem FAT32). I did some digging and some people said that this had something to do with my hard drive, which I don't want to believe. My old hard drive (a 500 GB 5200 RPM one) had broken sectors, so I had to buy a new 1 TB 7200 RPM hard drive (Seagate) - so I really don't want to accept that my *new* hard drive is broken too.

Comment: Can you share what "some people" said exactly by chance?

Comment: See this possible duplicate question....https://superuser.com/questions/991255/error-code-0x800701e3-while-installing-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: @Moab I already read that question, and that question's the place where I read the possibility that my HDD is broken